# cross correlation of more than two files in python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, numerical-methods, cross-correlation

I have a large numerical data and I must split it into 100 files and then compute `C(i,j) = 〈x(ti)x(tj)〉`. To  this  end, I  must  do  the  averaging  on  the  100  data  sets and make a matrix and plot it as a density plot.

So what I have done is:

```py
import numpy as np 

data = np.loadtxt('data1.txt')
np.split(data, 100)

lines_per_file = 10485
smallfile = None
small_filename_num = 1
with open("data1.txt", "r") as bigfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            if smallfile:
                smallfile.close()
            smallfile = open('File%d.txt' %  small_filename_num, "w")
            small_filename_num += 1
        smallfile.write(line)
    if smallfile:
        smallfile.close()
```

Now I want to calculate the cross correlation but I don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean by `C(i,j)  =〈x(ti)x(tj)>`?

Comment: Hi arefeh, (1) the sufficient statistics for correlation are probably the number of data and the summations of one column times another (you can look this up). So just accumulate the sufficient statistics from each file and then compute the correlation at the end. (2) However, are you sure you need to break up the data into multiple files? If you are really working with 100 x 10485 data, that is about 10^6, and I think numpy will handle that easily all at once.

Comment: @gofvonx `<something>` is a notation to indicate inner product or expected value in some contexts, especially in physics.